# How to filter the list based on advance button search using angular8

Tags: angular, search, filter

I am trying to filter the contents from the `Advanced search` tab, here i enter few fields and based on click on search i need to filter the list and when i click on reset, all the fields entered there must be cleared.

I have pasted the working link as well, can anyone help me out please.

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qwjsva)

Comment: This question reads like a requirement, not a focused/specific problem statement. Please review [ask] and include an [mcve] *in the question* and describe a *specific problem* you are having.

Comment: Yes it is a requirement, can i get a hint or small help of how to solve this?

Comment: That is not what [so] is intended for. Please review [ask].

Comment: Please go through angular formcontrol / reactive form. Create a search panel using that. On submit get the value and querying it over your json object. Please try to implement that and raise a separate question if you stuck on any specific scenario.

Comment: @SRana Thanks for your help. I have tried and updated the link. But it must work on AND basis, and if all fields are filled it works fine, but if i give one field then it doesnt work. Can You help me?

Answer (score 0):

Modify the below lines in your code and will work fine.

```
let search_obj = {groupCode:'1234',agentCode:'',agentName:'',phone:"",email:''}; //Assume you have searched only with groupcode
const data = this.agentList.filter(res =>
  res.groupCode === search_obj.groupCode || 
  res.agentCode === search_obj.agentCode ||
  res.agentName === search_obj.agentName ||
  res.phone === search_obj.phone ||
  res.email === search_obj.email 
)
```

Comment: Hi, is there anyway to give the filter list, like if only one field is given, then it must work on OR, and if more than one field is filled, then it must be a AND search basis